# Accessing Apollo's loading boolean outside of Mutation component

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

The `Mutation` component in `react-apollo` exposes a handy [loading](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations#errors) boolean in the render prop function which is ideal for adding loaders to the UI whilst a request is being made. In the example below my `Button` component calls the `createPlan` function when clicked which initiates a GraphQL mutation. Whilst this is happening a spinner appears on the button courtesy of the `loading` prop.

```
<Mutation mutation={CREATE_PLAN}>
  {(createPlan, { loading }) => (
    <Button
      onClick={() => createPlan({ variables: { input: {} } })}
      loading={loading}
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

The issue I have is that other aspects of my UI also need to change based on this `loading` boolean. I have tried lifting the `Mutation` component up the React tree so that I can manually pass the `loading` prop down to any components which rely on it, which works, but the page I am building has multiple mutations that can take place at any given time (such as deleting a plan, adding a single item in a plan, deleting a single item in a plan etc.) and having all of these `Mutation` components sitting at the page-level component feels very messy.

Is there a way that I can access the `loading` property outside of this `Mutation` component? If not, what is the best way to handle this problem? I have read that you can manually update the Apollo local state using the [update](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state#direct-writes) function on the `Mutation` component (see example below) but I haven't been able to work out how to access the `loading` value here (plus it feels like accessing the `loading` property of a specific mutation without having to manually write it to the cache yourself would be a common request).

```
<Mutation
  mutation={CREATE_PLAN}
  update={cache => {
    cache.writeData({
      data: {
        createPlanLoading: `I DON"T HAVE ACCESS TO THE LOADING BOOLEAN HERE`,
      },
    });
  }}
>
  {(createPlan, { loading }) => (
    <Button
      onClick={() => createPlan({ variables: { input: {} } })}
      loading={loading}
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem in my projects and yes, putting all mutations components at the page-level component is very messy. The best way I found to handle this is by creating React states. For instance:

```
const [createPlanLoading, setCreatePLanLoading] = React.useState(false);

...

<Mutation mutation={CREATE_PLAN} onCompleted={() => setCreatePLanLoading(false)}>
  {(createPlan, { loading }) => (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        createPlan({ variables: { input: {} } });
        setCreatePLanLoading(true);
      }
      loading={loading}
    >
      Save
    </Button>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense (although I am not currently using hooks). How would you then change the loading state back to `false` after the `Mutation` component changes?

Comment: @GuerillaRadio Using `onCompleted` Mutation props: `onCompleted={() => setCreatePLanLoading(false)}` this way you set `false` when mutation completes.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer with React States. However, when there are many different children it looks messy with so many variables.

I've made a bit update for it for these cases:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [loadingChilds, setLoading] = useState({});

  // check if at least one child item is loading, then show spinner
  const loading = Object.values(loadingChilds).reduce((t, value) => t || value, false);

  return (
  <div>
      {loading ? (
          <CircularProgress />
      ) : null}
      <Child1 setLoading={setLoading}/>
      <Child2 setLoading={setLoading}/>
  </div>
  );
};

const Child1 = ({ setLoading }) => {
  const [send, { loading }] = useMutation(MUTATION_NAME);

  useEffect(() => {
    // add info about state to the state object if it's changed
    setLoading((prev) => (prev.Child1 !== loading ? { ...prev, Child1: loading } : prev));
  });

  const someActionHandler = (variables) => {
    send({ variables});
  };



  return (
    <div>
      Child 1 Content
    </div>
  );
};


const Child2 = ({ setLoading }) => {
  const [send, { loading }] = useMutation(MUTATION_NAME2);

  useEffect(() => {
    // add info about state to the state object if it's changed
    setLoading((prev) => (prev.Child2 !== loading ? { ...prev, Child2: loading } : prev));
  });

  const someActionHandler = (variables) => {
    send({ variables});
  };



  return (
    <div>
      Child 2 Content
    </div>
  );
};
```